# Rails Tutorial --> how to "use session instead of cookies" (Chapter 8, exercise 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I'm stumped by chapter 8, exercise 2:

```
Use session instead of cookies so that users are automatically signed out when they close
their browsers.
```

Poking around here and github, it seems the way to accomplish this is to modify the SessionsController like so:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
...
```

But when I do that, I can no longer sign in:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

What else do I need to modify to authenticate using session instead of cookies?

Comment: what are the params being passed? Can you paste the output of tail -f log/development.log when performing this action? looks like your passing an empty hash via the form or looking for the wrong members in the params hash

Answer (score -1):

The clue is in the error `NoMethodError in SessionsController#create`

The # there means the create method in the SessionsController.

Comment: I solved this just by reverting to using `form_for(:session, url: sessions_path)` in the signup form (instead of `form_tag sessions_path`. But users are still signed in after quitting the browser, so I'm still not there ;)

Comment: Sorry!  I must have been tired when I answered.  You addressed the SessionController in your question.  Do you mind sharing your github link to your sample_app?